# Dynamic height and width of chatbot on webpage

Tags: jquery, css, html, chatbot

There is chatbot whose height and width need to be changed dynamically on the webpage. The chatbot is on python. Using an html snippet we are calling the function on the webpage to initiate the chatbot. 
I need an html or css code to make the height and width of the chatbot window dynamic. 
Below I have shared a small snippet of the code where I call the function to initiate it under  tag. How should I make the height and width dynamic. Please help.

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFF">
 Hello world
</body>
<script defer>
    function loadChatWidget() {
    chatteron.init({
    clientID : "",
     bubbleUrl: "",

    theme    : {
      bubble: {
        width: 80,
        right : 10,
        bottom : 22,

       },
      },
    height: 500
  });
 }
  </script>
  <script defer src=""   onload="loadChatWidget();">
  </script>


  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `document.body.clientWidth` and `document.body.clientHeight` in your script to get the dimensions of the screen and then calculate width depending upon the ratio/percentage you have in mind.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjeu8sxf/1/)

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth).